# Android: CountDownTimer not working

Tags: android, countdown, countdowntimer

I'm trying to create a countdown timer for my app but after doing this, the `TextView` where it should show the remaining time doesn't show anything so my timer is not working. I don't know if I am missed something.

Here is my timer:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.layout7);
         cronometro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cronometro);
         new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    cronometro.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                   cronometro.setText("done!"); 
                }
             }.start();
```

**Edit:** As Simon said and changing some things the timer works now. Is there a way of setting the format into MM:SS

Comment: Are you doing this in onCreate()?  If so, your UI is not yet built so you won't see anything.  Try onWindowFocusChanged()

Comment: Yes its being done onCreate and the UI is built:

Comment: The UI is not built until after onCreate()

Comment: I test your codes and run it on onCreate(), mine is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cronometro.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(millisUntilFinished/1000));
```